# Using location with different control types

Tags: c#

I want to use the following method.

```
private void LocationChange(Object obj, int first, int second) 
{ 
     // so then if i say 

    obj.Location = new Point(first,second);
}
```

but this won't work for me is there a way around this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Location` is a property of [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx), you ought to make the parameter of that type:

```
private void LocationChange(Control control, int first, int second) 
{ 
    control.Location = new Point(first,second);
}
```

You can then pass any type that subclasses `Control` into that method.

I'm not sure *why* you would allow any `object` to be passed into the method if it's meant to operate on a Control specifically, but if you had some other, non-control-specific logic in there, you could cast the parameter, like so:

```
private void LocationChange(Object obj, int first, int second) 
{ 
    // Logic that operates on the object regardless of its type goes here...
    // Although I'm not sure what that logic would be. :)

    // This check works since .NET 2.0 (I believe?) and lets you avoid 
    // an InvalidCastException if obj happens NOT to be a subclass of Control...
    if(obj is Control)
    {
        ((Control)obj).Location = new Point(first,second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Object doesn't have property Location..
This should do the trick.

```
private void LocationChange(Object obj, int first, int second) 
{ 
     // so then if i say 
    if (obj is Control)
    {
       (obj as Control).Location = new Point(first,second);
    }       
}
```

Comment: If the `is` operator passes, you can just cast directly. No need to use the `as` operator in conjunction.